# If $M$ is a compact $d$-dimensional manifold with nonempty boundary, then $H^d(M)=0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, de-rham-cohomology

The accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439065/is-the-jacobian-a-divergence-of-some-vector-field-manifolds) contains the following statement:

> If $M$ is a compact $d$-dimensional manifold with nonempty boundary, then $H^d(M)=0$.

This does not look obvious to me, so I thought it was worth asking. Can you give a proof of this statement (or, at least, a reference)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604044/top-homology-of-an-oriented-compact-connected-smooth-manifold-with-boundary

Comment: It would be nice if one could give an informal proof of this statement without the use of Poincaré-Lefschetz Duality, like Lavinias answer to the question posted by John on the same statement for homology.

Comment: Okay, I am giving it a try. First, take a finite simplicial structure on $M$ and use the fact that de-rham cohomology is isomorphic to real simplicial cohomology.  The top dimensional simplicial cohomology is the $\mathbb R$-vectorspace generated by the the maps $\alpha_i$, where $i$ runs over the number of all $n$-simplices and $\alpha_i$ assigns the $i$-th $n$-simplex $\omega_i$ the number $1$ and every other $n$-simplex the number $0$.

Comment: To show that $H^d(M) = 0$, it there suffices to show that each of the $\alpha_i$ is a coboundary, i.e, $\alpha_i$ can be described as a map on the $n-1$ simplices- In order to do that, try to carefully "invert" the argument used by Lavina in her proof for the vanishing of top homology, using the fact that collection of $n-1$ simplices on $\partial M$ give you enough freedom to do so.

Comment: Use the following idea to define a cochain $\beta_i$ with $\delta(\beta_i) = \alpha_i$. First, assign all the (oriented) $n-1$ simplices on $\omega_i$ numbers that add up to $1$ in total. The coboundary of the map defined this way is not necessarily $\alpha_i$, the problem is some $n$-simplices adjacent to $\omega_i$ will be assigned a non-zero value. Now how do you proceed ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $M$ is compact and smooth, there exists a finite triangulation $T$ of $M$. The de Rham Theorem now tells you now that the de Rham cohomology of differential forms is isomorphic to the real simplicial cohomology on $M$ induced by $T$. Denote by $C^*_T(M,\mathbb R)$ the corresponding real simplicial cochain complex.

For a fixed (oriented) $d$-simplex $\omega$ of $T$, consider the associated *dual* cochain $\alpha \in C_T^d(M,\mathbb R)$ that evaluates to $1$ at $\omega$ and to $0$ at every other $d$-simplex. As $C_T^d(M,\mathbb R)$ is generated by the collection of all such *dual* cochains, showing that $\alpha$ is a coboundary will suffice to prove that $H^d(M) = 0$.

As $M$ can WLoG assumed to be path-connected, we can choose a sequence $\omega = \omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots,\omega_n$ of distinct *wandering* oriented $d$ simplices, such that for $k=1,\dots,n$, $\omega_k$ doesn't share a face with any other member of this sequence other than with $\omega_{k-1}$ and $\omega_{k+1}$,  such that two consecutive members $\omega_k$ and $\omega_{k+1}$ have *precisley* one d-1 face $\sigma_k$ in common, and such that $\omega_n$ has a face $\sigma_n$ lying in $\partial M \neq \emptyset$.

Define a cochain $\beta \in C^{d-1}_T(M,\mathbb R)$ by assigning the value $\pm 1$ to the (oriented) simplicies $\sigma_k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ and $0$ to any other $d-1$ simplex. By choosing the right signs each time, one can guarantee that $\delta \beta (\omega_k) = 0$ for every $k \geq 2$ and $\delta \beta(\omega) = \delta \beta (\omega_1) = 1$. Moreover, from the definition of $\beta$ and the choice of our sequence $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$, we see that $\delta \beta = 0$ on *any* $d$-simplex other than $\omega$. Thus, $\delta \beta = \alpha$, so $\alpha$ indeed is a coboundary.

Comment: The de Rham theorem and the existence of triangulations are results considerably more complex than Poincaré duality...

Comment: You also need the fact that singular cohomology coincides with the simplicial cohomology for a specific triangulation.

Comment: In order to even apply Poincaré-Lefschetz duality, you need to pass from de Rham cohomology to singular cohomology. Thus, you certainly need the de Rham theorem. Secondly, although the existence of a triangulation might be a deeper result than Poincaré-Lefschetz duality, simply applying the latter result without knowing all the machinery behind it doesn't give you any real *understanding* on why this result is true. My goal was to give a visual, combinatorial proof of this fact, and this is, as far as I know, best achieved when passing to the world of simplicial complexes.

Comment: Also, my proof works in the case when $M$ is not oriented. In this case, you cannot even apply Poincaré-Lefschetz duality.